# Professor asked me to hand in a plagarism report. How do I do it?

Tags: plagiarism, projects

My professor told me to submit plagiarism report of my project work. How do I do it? I have tried online softwares but they are not working.

Comment: First, why don't ask the prof? Second, this forum is not so good for this question. Third, if you find a forum to ask this question, ask it better: explain what "not working" means in your context, which online softwares you used, what kind of Project work, what you did exactly etc.

Comment: Please explain on which ground your professor asks for this report.

Comment: Are they asking for a "report" or just a statement that you developed the project ethically and properly cited sources?

Comment: I guess there is a standard software simply providing a report that you have to attach to your manuscript. Why not ask your School, it seems to be standard procedure.

Comment: It isn't clear to us what exactly your professor is asking for.  It seems likely that this is in response to some local institutional rule that requires you to run a particular software on your document and possibly write a response based on the results.  Thus the best solution to your problem will be to ask for help at your institution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many universities have plagiarism software that is used for detecting plagiarism in theses or other project reports. At my previous institution there was a time when students were not allowed to submit their thesis and graduate without first running their thesis through this software and providing the report.

If this is the type of thing that is begin asked, there should be an official web page where you can submit your document and generate a report. We won't be able to help you with those details, you'll need to talk to local administrators to get help with that.